# Issues with jQuery delay function

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a customer review section of my page where it has a div showing names in a row and an arrow that moves to each name after a few seconds. However, when I type in my jQuery for it to wait a few seconds so clients can read the first testimonial, it automatically jumps the number of pixels, despite the fact that I put in the code to delay that. What's going on here?

HTML:

```
<div class="cust-name div-box" style="padding: 0;">
   <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
       <p>Zach</p>
       <p>Zach</p>
       <p>Zach</p>
       <p>Zach</p>
   </div>
   <div class="arrow-up"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $upArrow = $('.arrow-up');

// $(document).ready(function() {
//     $upArrow.delay(5000).css("left", "50px");
// });

$upArrow.hide();
$upArrow.show(2000).css("left", "25px");
$upArrow.delay(2000);
$upArrow.css("left", "50px");
```

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue.
>   Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will
>   not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which **do not
>   use the effects** queue.

`.css()` do not use effects queue, so, the better way is to use `setTimeout()`;

For your code:

```
$upArrow.hide().show(2000).css("left", "25px");
setTimeout(function() { $upArrow.css("left", "50px"); }, 2000);
```

Comment: Just put that in my code and it works! Thanks for your help! I know I'm trying to reinforce my jQuery and JS learning so that way I won't forget it so simple things like this helps!

Comment: I have another question - how would I loop through the timeout functions infinitely so that way it automatically shows the testimonials?

Comment: Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with jquery's delay method as well. Instead you could try using `setTimeout();`.

Try this:

```
$upArrow.hide();

$upArrow.show(2000).css("left", "25px");

var alterCss = function() {
 $upArrow.css('left', '50px');
};

setTimeout(alterCss, 2000);
```

I'm not sure if this will work for you, but it would be the first thing I would try since setTimeout should provide the same effect.

Comment: I think the reason you're having trouble with `delay()` is because it is meant to be chained with other function calls. For instance:

`$upArrow.show(2000).css("left", "25px").delay(2000).css("left", "50px");`

But I'm not sure if that would work for you. I recommend that you just try different ways and one is bound to work.